# Что это за алгоритм, написаный на scala

Tags: scala

Что это за алгоритм, как он называется? Не я его писал

```
def foo[T](v: List[T])(implicit i: T => Ordered[T]): List[T] = {
    def t: (List[T] => (List[T], List[T])) = {
      case Nil => (Nil, Nil)
      case b :: Nil => (b :: Nil, Nil)
      case c :: d :: e =>
        val (f, g) = t(e)
        (c :: f, d :: g)
    }

    def l(q: List[T], t: List[T]): List[T] =
      (q, t) match {
        case (c, Nil) => c
        case (Nil, d) => d
        case (e :: f, g :: h) =>
          if (e > g)
            g :: l(q, h)
          else
            e :: l(f, t)
      }

    v match {
      case Nil | _ :: Nil =>
        v
      case _ =>
        val (a, b) = t(v)
        val c = foo(a)
        val d = foo(b)
        l(c, d)
    }
}
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что определение алгоритма по коду - бесполезный вопрос.

Comment: Нет, потому что я больше не знаю, к кому еще можно обратиться, кто знает этот язык, мне просто очень нужно знать название этого алгоритма\. чтобы написать его на python и мне нужно просто название этого алгоритма, сказали что какой то известный, но написан на scala, поэтому не гуглится

Comment: совершенно необязательно знать название алгоритма, чтобы перевести код со скалы в питон. Просто переводите строчку за строчкой

Answer (score 1):

Ну особо не вникая, можно сказать что это сортировка похожая на [quick sort](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).
По коду видно сначала происходит разбивка списка на две части и потом они рекурсивно сортируются.
Если это не quick sort, то можно поискать алгоритмы которые при сортировке разбивают исходный массив на две части.

Answer (score 0):

Это [merge sort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)

- `t` разделяет список на два равной длинны
- `l` сливает два сортированных списка